# Arma 3 player ID

Tags: arma-3

I am creating my account to play a Arma 3 mod called Breaking Point. To create an account I need to provide my Arma 3 player ID.

Where can I find my player ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have registered properly and are now trying to provide the Player ID information you need to go to your profile in Arma 3 by selecting Configure and Profile from the main menu. Your player ID is displayed there and can be entered into the appropriate location. Make sure you add the [] around the number however or it will appear invalid.

Full steps with pictures and such can be found on the [wiki for the mod](http://breakingpointmod.com/wiki/index.php?title=Whitelisting).